# Multi Record via XML to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, sql-update

I wish to pass the following XML as a string to SQL and `UPDATE` the target table row depending according to the existing table columns identified by `EventID` and `GROUP`.....

```
<Item>
    <GroupItem>
        <Group1>A</Group1>
        <Price>100</Price>
        <Location>Here</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <GroupItem>
        <Group2>B</Group2>
        <Price>200</Price>
        <Location>There</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <GroupItem>
        <Group3>C</Group3>
        <Price>300</Price>
        <Location>Everywhere</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <EVENTID>12345</EVENTID>
    <MATCHED>100</MATCHED>
</Item>
```

So in this example I want to update the table row that has an `EventID` of 12345 and supply values for columns:  `GROUP1 = A`, `GROUP2 = B`, `GROUP3 = C`....

Any help to unravel the mess I am in (once again) would appreciated....

TARGET TABLE Structure follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GROUPTABLE](
[EventID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Group1A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1C] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1D] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group2A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group2B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group2_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group2_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group3A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group3B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group3_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group3_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group4A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group4B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group4_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group4_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_GROUPTABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EventID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Whilst this may not conceptually make sense - this is not the exact table I am using in my application - (I dont want to give too much away), but this structure mimics exactly what I am trying to do in my 'real' table....

Comment: Please tag which SQL engine you are using

Comment: Engine?.... I am using vbnet with SQl Server .. Is that what you meant....?

Comment: Is this XML under your control? Other words: Would you be allowed/able to change this structure? Secondly: Do you really want nothing else than to set a column called "Group1" with the Value "A" , "Group2" with "B". Nothing to do with Price and Location? What about "Matched"?

Comment: Change the structure...not sure what you mean...  the database is under my control alone. It is an application for my use...

I want the Column labrelled Group1 to be set to whatever value is passed in via the XML...same for Group2 etc. and yes, price and location too.. I figured if someone responded to the Group alone I could simply replicate the code for Price , location etc.

Comment: 'Matched' also would need to be updated  according to the value passed in via XML - as determined by the EventID table row ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### UPDATE2

Just copy the whole code block in an empty query window and try it out...

```
/*
This is your mimic table
Btw: It is - in almost all cases! - a very bad idea to store related data in a table like data1, data2, data3...
If possible you should introduce a table GroupValues with a foreign key onto group table
*/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GROUPTABLE](
[EventID] [int] NOT NULL,
[Group1A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group1_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group1_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group2A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group2B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group2_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group2_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group3A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group3B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group3_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group3_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group4A] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group4B] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Group4_Matched] [float] NULL,
[Group4_Location] [nvarchar](50) NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_GROUPTABLE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[EventID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY];

--here I insert two dummy rows
INSERT INTO GROUPTABLE VALUES
 (1,   'Gr1A','Gr1B',111,'Gr1Location'
      ,'Gr2A','Gr2B',222,'Gr2Location'
      ,'Gr3A','Gr3B',333,'Gr3Location'
      ,'Gr4A','Gr4B',444,'Gr4Location'
      )
,(12345,'Gr1A','Gr1B',111,'Gr1Location'
       ,'Gr2A','Gr2B',222,'Gr2Location'
       ,'Gr3A','Gr3B',333,'Gr3Location'
       ,'Gr4A','Gr4B',444,'Gr4Location'
      );

--one test to show the data
SELECT * FROM dbo.GROUPTABLE;

--Here's your XML
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<Item>
    <GroupItem>
        <Group1>A</Group1>
        <Price>100</Price>
        <Location>Here</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <GroupItem>
        <Group2>B</Group2>
        <Price>200</Price>
        <Location>There</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <GroupItem>
        <Group3>C</Group3>
        <Price>300</Price>
        <Location>Everywhere</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <EVENTID>12345</EVENTID>
    <MATCHED>100</MATCHED>
</Item>';

/*
And this is the UPDATE
If necessary you might use .query() to get the nodes and save repeated XPath-navigation
Anyway: Much better was a 
<Item>
    <GroupItem group="A">
        <Group>A</Group>
        <Price>100</Price>
        ...
    <GroupItem group="B">
        <Group>A</Group>
        <Price>100</Price>
        ...
to avoid differint element names
*/

UPDATE dbo.GROUPTABLE
SET Group1A         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group1"])[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group2A         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group2"])[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group3A         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group3"])[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group4A         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group4"])[1]','varchar(max)')

   ,Group1B         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group1"]/../Price)[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group2B         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group2"]/../Price)[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group3B         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group3"]/../Price)[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group4B         = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group4"]/../Price)[1]','varchar(max)')

   ,Group1_Matched  = @XML.value('(/Item/MATCHED)[1]','float')
   ,Group2_Matched  = @XML.value('(/Item/MATCHED)[1]','float')
   ,Group3_Matched  = @XML.value('(/Item/MATCHED)[1]','float')
   ,Group4_Matched  = @XML.value('(/Item/MATCHED)[1]','float')

   ,Group1_Location = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group1"]/../Location)[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group2_Location = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group2"]/../Location)[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group3_Location = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group3"]/../Location)[1]','varchar(max)')
   ,Group4_Location = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group4"]/../Location)[1]','varchar(max)')

WHERE EventID=@XML.value('(/Item/EVENTID)[1]','int');

--Here you see, that the item' value changed for EventID=12345
SELECT * FROM dbo.GROUPTABLE;

--Clean Up
--DROP TABLE dbo.GROUPTABLE
```

#### UPDATE

With this query you get all your data in one go

```
SELECT @XML.value('(/Item/EVENTID)[1]','int') AS EventId
      ,@XML.value('(/Item/MATCHED)[1]','int') AS Matched
      ,A.B.value('local-name(*[position()=1][1])','varchar(max)') AS GroupName
      ,A.B.value('*[position()=1][1]','varchar(max)') AS FirstNode
      ,A.B.value('Price[1]','decimal(12,4)') AS Price
      ,A.B.value('Location[1]','varchar(max)') AS Location
FROM @XML.nodes('/Item/GroupItem') AS A(B)
```

The result

```
12345   100 Group1  A   100.0000    Here
12345   100 Group2  B   200.0000    There
12345   100 Group3  C   300.0000    Everywhere
```

#### previous

Actually I doubt that the description you give really is what you want :-), but this was an approach to achieve what I understood:

```
DECLARE @XML XML=
'<Item>
    <GroupItem>
        <Group1>A</Group1>
        <Price>100</Price>
        <Location>Here</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <GroupItem>
        <Group2>B</Group2>
        <Price>200</Price>
        <Location>There</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <GroupItem>
        <Group3>C</Group3>
        <Price>300</Price>
        <Location>Everywhere</Location>
    </GroupItem>

    <EVENTID>12345</EVENTID>
    <MATCHED>100</MATCHED>
</Item>';
```

Declare a table variable to fill it with test data

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Group1 VARCHAR(10),Group2 VARCHAR(10),Group3 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (3456,'Test1','Test2','Test3')
,(12345,'Test1','Test2','Test3');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

The result

```
3456    Test1   Test2   Test3
12345   Test1   Test2   Test3
```

Change the row with ID=12345

```
UPDATE @tbl SET Group1 = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group1"])[1]','varchar(max)')
               ,Group2 = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group2"])[1]','varchar(max)')
               ,Group3 = @XML.value('(/Item/GroupItem/*[local-name(.)="Group3"])[1]','varchar(max)')
WHERE ID=@XML.value('(/Item/EVENTID)[1]','int');
```

The result

```
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

3456    Test1   Test2   Test3
12345   A       B       C
```

Comment: Wow  - that was fast!

Comment: Shungo -With this I can make significant strides forward, thank you again.

Comment: @user6167266, glad to read this! I just added a query which would get all data out in one go. You might use `SELECT col1,col2, ... INTO #tempTable FROM ...` Specifying the `INTO #tempTable` would put the data into a table. From there you could do a multiline update using `JOIN`. Or put the query into a `CTE`...

Comment: @user6167266 One thing which would improve the structure was to let the  element's names be the same, like this `<GroupItem id="1"><GroupValue>A</GroupValue><Price>...` Elements carrying the same information should be called the same. The information, that this is "Group 2" or "Group 1" is better as meta-data-attribut placed into the parent node...

Comment: @user6167266 and one egoistic comment: As you just have crossed the 15 reputation points (with a little push from my side) it would be very kind to click the upvote, if you like my answer. Thx!

Comment: Shnugo... I note your comment above... 
>>I just added a query which would get all data out in one go. You might use SELECT col1,col2, ... INTO #tempTable FROM ... Specifying the INTO #tempTable would put the data into a table. From there you could do a multiline update using JOIN. Or put the query into a CTE...
>> 
are you saying that I could add each record into the TEMPTable using a single stored procedure and then call another SProc to perform a multiline UPDATE...? Are you able to illustrate with another excellent example..? I am guessing this may speed things up... ?

Comment: @user6167266 Please use the edit option of your question to add the target table's structure...

Comment: Hi @user6167266, Sorry for the late answer. I found your edit by chance because I tend to come back to answers were I remember there was something left. Next time please add a comment with `@Shnugo`. This will trigger an alert. Btw: Without *this* comment you would not notice, that there's an update with my answer :-) Please vote up if you like it Thx